# android Gridview customization

Tags: android

is there any way to make gridview items like cell(column) have diffrent size? like one column have 2x height and width on another one ? or made ability to gridview that we gave the size on call for each one ?
this is what im looking for :

[image]

plus ive check all of these links and source and none of them gives me The Costume "Gridview" 
method.

https://github.com/benmonro/PulseLauncherGrid

https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary

i guess this aint possible for gridview in android right ?

Comment: the layout in your image can be achieved using GridLayout...

Comment: @GopalRao , thanks for suggestion ,  problem is i must set adapter to gridview and gridlayout doesnt support that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default `GridView` doesn't work properly with that but check this link: http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/

Comment: thanks for the link , is it possible to set adaptor for this gridview ?

Comment: from the example source I can see StaggeredAdapter.java